# How to animate row when children changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How do you achieve the smooth transition when the checkmark is added?

[image]

Clicking the element will setState update the `pressAttention` variable, and therefore add the checkmark widget to the list of children of the row.
For now it just instantly rebuilds the row, and adds the checkmark, but I would really like it to smoothly do as in the GIF.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      widget.amount,
      style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
    ),
    if (pressAttention)
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: Container(
          width: 23,
          height: 23,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              MyIcons.checkmarkThick,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  late Animation<double> _opacityAnimation;
  late Animation _colorAnimation;
  late AnimationController _controller;

  var pressAttention = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this)
          ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _animation = Tween(begin: 15.0, end: 0.0).animate(_controller);
    _opacityAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller);

    _colorAnimation =
        ColorTween(begin: Colors.grey, end: Colors.purple).animate(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              onTap: () {
                if (pressAttention) {
                  _controller.forward();
                } else {
                  _controller.reverse();
                }
                setState(() {
                  pressAttention = !pressAttention;
                });
              },
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _controller,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: _colorAnimation.value),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Transform.translate(
                            offset: Offset(_animation.value, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              '1000',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Opacity(
                            opacity: _opacityAnimation.value,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.check,
                                    size: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: At first it seems great, but I am a bit worried with the hard-coded offset, it kind of removes all responsiveness. This could be solved by calculating the offset with MediaQuery or something.

Overall this seems a bit cumbersome, I really hoped it was possible to solve with some of the animation widgets already there to not rely on calculating sizes/offsets/positions myself.

In my code, there isn't anything specifying the distance between the two elements other than their natural sizes and padding, so it is nice and responsive.

Comment: actually the only hard-code offset is _animation = Tween(begin: 15.0, end: 0.0).animate(_controller); and it is not hard-coded. begin: 15.0 is calculated from icon size.  and icon size is a static value. Icon size is sum of these value: 10 (padding left) + 8 (padding left and right of icon) + 13 (icon size)  = 31. I divided  by 2 and rounded 31 to  15. So 15 is not hardcoded.

Comment: Ah yes I see, that makes sense. I will try to play around with it some more and see what kind of conclusion I get to. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It does. I had hoped for an easier way, something like using a AnimatedContainer where is automatically tweens between properties, but I guess the closest you can get is to use a AnimatedSwitcher, so this definitely helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of [Animated Widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/animation). Set their behaviours and durations and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have tried using what I thought would make sense, but I have had no luck in achieving the result I want.


I would appreciate a more specific answer, this is a bit too vague.


It is pretty straight forward when it is properties like size, color and so on, but when it is the children property that changes, I just can't seem to find anything that works. Thanks.